# Not getting Intellisense function parameters in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Using `Visual Studio 2010`, I am typing in the name of a function as follows:

```
MyClass mc = MyClassOfStaticMethods.GetMyClassInstance(
```

The method `GetMyClassInstance` takes two parameters, but when I type the above I am not getting the `Intellisense` showing me the parameter list for the method.  Why not?

Comment: and I'm guessing it's there :) - if you type in the params (manually) does it compile? You may have a mismatch of .NET versions if in lib, or something. Lambda params also behave differently. Make sure you don't have some duplicate naming (or a 'red' error when in intellisense list) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Possible guesses

- `GetMyClassInstance` is instance method so intellisense can't pick method itself, and hence arguments.
- method is hidden from intellisense.
- your expectation of the method does not match with reality (i.e. you expect newer/older version of the method that you actually have).